# Remove the Root Password MySQL

Tags: mysql, root

On a test server I would like to remove the root password in order to test some security.

I don't want to change the password or set it to blank (which is what every guide online seems to tell you to do) I just want root to not need a password to authenticate.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Don't see the point - just make sure the root account can not be used for remote logins.

Comment: There is no good reason to do this.

Comment: The reason is I want to run some tests for a root account without a password, with a fresh install this is possible but not in one where I have set the password before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as Kerry suggested in his comment was that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make sense to just disable remote logins as root, instead only allow local as root?

Comment: That doesn't help my testing I am afraid.